# Swapping two points in a list of points

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to exchange the two data points in a list, like `{0.8,0.4}` into `{0.4,0.8}`.

**So how can make it easier without doing it manually?**

Comment: `Reverse @ {0.8, 0.4}`

Answer (score 5):

All these will take `{0.8,0.4}` and transform it into  `{0.4,0.8}`

```
Reverse[{0.8,0.4}]
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

{0.8,0.4}/.{x_,y_}->{y,x}
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

RotateLeft@{0.8,0.4}
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

RotateRight@{0.8,0.4}
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

Part[{0.8,0.4}, {2,1}]
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

Sort[{0.8,0.4}]
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

Dot[{0.8,0.4},{{0,1},{1,0}}]
(* {0.4,0.8} *)

ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]@{0.8,0.4}
(* {0.4,0.8} *)
```

Comment: What am I missing?